# Why is <br> changed to <br />?

Tags: blocks, 9

After I edit a block in *Full HTML* form CKEditor on *Source mode* and save, Drupal changes `<br>` to `<br />`.

Drupal also seems to me to unify some HTML tags into one line.

This

```html
<p>
<!-- -->
<br>
```

Becomes something like this

```html
<p><!-- --><br />
```

In /admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html the only filters that are on are:

- Align images
- Caption images
- Track images uploaded via a text editor

The *Correct faulty and chopped off HTML* filter isn't on.

It might be that the very work on *Full HTML* mode causes this because it's "full" without any sugar syntax. If so, manually changing the HTML level of nearly 30 blocks and also hundreds of nodes to *Restriced HTML* is not something I want to do.

Why is this happening? How do I prevent it?

Comment: "Full HTML" is just a label of a text format, which is installed in Drupal by default. A text format is essentially the sum of its filters. CKEditor also does things. I can't determine from the Question if this is actually about CKEditor.

Comment: They both do the same thing, and `<br />` is compatible with more doctypes, which is why the editor would default to this. What is your reasoning behind wanting to use `<br>` tags instead?

Comment: Is this question simply https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3351660 ?

Comment: @Jaypan using `<br>` instead `<br />` is just easier for me to read in condensed HTML text., the same goes for multi-line instead single-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<br>` is changed to `<br />` because all the HTML markup used as block or node content is passed to [`Html::normalize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Anormalize/9), which calls [`Html::serialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aserialize/9) which uses [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php). The latter is what changes `<br>` to `<br />`. (It would also do the same for any tag without content.)

```php
public static function serialize(\DOMDocument $document) {
  $body_node = $document->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
  $html = '';
  if ($body_node !== NULL) {
    foreach ($body_node->getElementsByTagName('script') as $node) {
      static::escapeCdataElement($node);
    }
    foreach ($body_node->getElementsByTagName('style') as $node) {
      static::escapeCdataElement($node, '/*', '*/');
    }
    foreach ($body_node->childNodes as $node) {
      $html .= $document->saveXML($node);
    }
  }
  return $html;
}
```

That is not possible to change.

As for why the text is shown on a single line, that is what CKEditor 5 actually does. The issue linked by @cilefen in his comment ([CKEditor 5 saves content as single line HTML making revision diffing impossible](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3351660)) contains a link to a feature request opened in the CKEditor 5 issue queue ([Output formatted HTML code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8668)).
That needs to be implemented in CKEditor 5; then Drupal needs to use the release it implements that.

Comment: apaderno, thank you. I think that the best workaround for both problems is just working on the HTML in a native app text editor (such as Geany or VSCode), change it from there and then re-paste it edited into the block source code.

Comment: It will not work to avoid `<br>` is changed to `<br />`, though, as `Html::normalize()` is always called by Drupal when a node/block is saved.

Comment: Yes, I meant, it will be easy to edit outside and paste into Drupal but if the HTML is small (say, about 50 lines) than it's okay from Drupal. Thanks again for your help.